# Saber si el foco esta sobre un elemento Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

tengo eventos en varios elementos y quiero que se ejecuten solo cuando tienen el foco

```
  <ul ref="lista" v-else class="orderlines">

     <li  @keyup='deletedItem' @click="setActive(n)"   v-for="n in DetalleVenta" :key="n.id" :class="{ 'orderline selected': activeIndex === n.IdProductoSucursal}" class="orderline">

</li>

</ul>
```

**JS**

```
    mounted () {

          document.addEventListener("keyup", this.deletedItem);


  },
  methods: {


    deletedItem () {

                    if(event.keyCode==8){                   
                    var index=this.DetalleVenta.findIndex(x=>x.IdProductoSucursal==this.activeIndex)
                    this.DetalleVenta.splice(index, 1);    

              }

}
```

Lo que hace el siguente codigo , es ejecuta el evento `deletedItem` cuando se preciona la tecla borrar (keyCode==8), ahora solo quiero **que se ejecute , si el foco se encuentra sobre la lista**

Se me ocurre utilizar un flag ,pero busco una manera mas limpia de hacerlo , por ejemplo comprobar si el foco esta sobre la lista

Gracias

Comment: Puedes intentar con `@focus`

Comment: @JonathanOrta  no funciono , el foco lo pongo en un input , pero igual el evento se ejecuta

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos maneras de realizar esto:

```
@keypress.delete="miFuncion"
```

o de forma nativa

```
@keypress.native.delete="miFuncion"
```

Comment: la idea es ejecutar varias funciones , pero de igual manera probé lo que mencionas , y el evento no se ejecuta